# What is new in HTML5/CSS3?

Tags: html5, css3, css, xhtml, html

I've seen [this site](http://diveintohtml5.org/) and [this site](http://www.html5rocks.com/), but that's a lot to digest. What are the main things about HTML5 that make it different/better than regular old (X)HTML/CSS?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

HTML5 is *huge*, but also **awesome**.

In my view, it is mostly about *interoperability*. The spec goes and specifies even edge cases to try and make sure that **all browsers read the markup the same way**.

In second place, HTML5 has video and audio, which do exactly what the name says it does. If you want to include video or audio, HTML5 should reduce your plugin needs.

In third place, HTML5 includes lots of accessibility and semantic help. For instance, elements like `<section>` and `<article>` help machines figure out what content is supposed to be. New input types like `<input type=email>` can also be useful for the same reasons, although the new input types include custom UIs which make them useful even for "common" human readers.

Note that the new Forms features are much more than new input types. It also includes support for placeholder text and several other attributes.

HTML5 includes `<canvas>`, which allows drawing 2D(and, with WebGL, 3D) shapes like charts or even render games.

Old behavior is now standardized, such as Internet Explorer's ancient `contentEditable`.

The DOCTYPE is finally decent! You can now actually memorize it! `<!DOCTYPE html>`

Specifying encoding is also easier, with `<meta charset=utf-8>`.

If you want to send data to the client and associate it with elements, you can now do it with custom attributes. For instance, `<div data-status=open>Open</div>` is now finally allowed. Note that custom attribute names must be prefixed with `data-`.

You can now include SVG and MathML in HTML documents. Previously, you could only do it with XHTML documents.

Among the multiple new functions and fields HTML5 defines, one of the most impressive is classList, which enables you to manipulate the class attribute more easily. Instead of having to getAttribute/setAttribute and use complex hacks to figure out which classes an element has and remove a specific class from that element, classList makes those hard situations very simple.

There are also multiple related specs, such as Web Workers, Web Sockets and IndexedDB, which are not really part of HTML5 but everybody talks about them as if they were. They are very useful for taking advantage of multi-core computers, communicating with servers and storing data locally.

As for CSS3, it includes support for *animations*, *transitions*, *rounded borders* and the [flexible box model](http://hacks.mozilla.org/2010/04/the-css-3-flexible-box-model/).

Also new in CSS3 are the new selectors, which make it simpler to match specific elements on a page(such as only the odd or even rows in a table).

Opacity, new units, marquee and ruby are also part of CSS3.

I think that pretty much covers all important parts.

Comment: **Excellent** run-down.

Comment: Good work on hitting all the major points.

Comment: It's worth mentioning that HTML5 is currently just a Working Draft, and that it hasn't been fully finalised yet.

Comment: @Django Reinhardt As WHATWG says, not all HTML5 features are at the same stage. Some are more already widely implemented, others will take some more time. Implementation is what really matters when developing web sites, and the spec status isn't a good measurement for that. You might also want to look at the WHATWG FAQ.

Comment: Did they get rid of needing quotation marks for valid XHTML attributes?

Comment: @Lotus Notes - I know I took a long time to answer, but I guess better late than never. XHTML is XML, so you need quotation marks when the XML spec requires them. As for HTML5, the answer is "it depends on what characters the attribute value contains".

Answer (score 18):

To keep track of features and specifications support you can check [When can I use](http://caniuse.com/). It includes HTML5 and CSS3 features and things like SVG, PNG, CSS2.1 and CSS2. It also tracks their status of approval (Recommendation, Proposed Recommendation, Candidate Recommendation, Working Draft, IETF standard). [FindMeByIP](http://www.findmebyip.com/litmus/) maintains matrices of supported CSS3 features only, by browser.

Some rejiggering and simplification of syntax took place in the nuts and bolts:

- Simplified doctype string: `<!DOCTYPE html>`
- Simplified `language` attribute for `<html>` tag: `<html lang="en">`
  (can still include `xmlns` and `xml:lang` if you want XML compliance)
- Dedicated `<meta>` tag for `charset`: `<meta charset="utf-8" />`
- `script` no longer accepts `type` attribute, requires `charset` for remote scripts:
  `<script src="/media/js/jquery.js" charset="utf-8"></script>`(inline scripts need no additional attributes at all)

HTML5 brings the ability for your markup to be much more *semantic*, and overall much easier to read/write and have smaller file sizes. Instead of having `<div id="nav">`, you just have `<nav>`. Doesn't seem like much but it adds up.

Many elements from XHTML1 and HTML4 have been deprecated. The following elements are not supported in HTML5: `<acronym>`, `<applet>`, `<basefont>`, `<big>`, `<center>`, `<dir>`, `<font>`, `<frame>`, `<frameset>`, `<noframes>`, `<s>`, `<strike>`, `<tt>`, `<u>` and `<xmp>`.

Several new elements in HTML5 are meant to only add more semantic markup, and will do nothing except provide a more meaningful alternative to `<div>`. These new elements include: `<article>`, `<section>`, `<aside>`, `<hgroup>`, `<header>`, `<footer>`, `<nav>`, `<time>`, `<mark>`, `<figure>`, and `<figcaption>`.

HTML5 forms are *greatly* improved.

New Input Types

- [color](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/number-state.html#color-state), [email](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/states-of-the-type-attribute.html#e-mail-state), [date](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/states-of-the-type-attribute.html#date-state), [month](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/states-of-the-type-attribute.html#month-state), [week](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/states-of-the-type-attribute.html#week-state), [time](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/states-of-the-type-attribute.html#time-state), [datetime](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/states-of-the-type-attribute.html#date-and-time-state), [datetime-local](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/states-of-the-type-attribute.html#local-date-and-time-state), [number](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/number-state.html#number-state), [range](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/number-state.html#range-state), [search](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/states-of-the-type-attribute.html#text-state-and-search-state), [tel](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/states-of-the-type-attribute.html#telephone-state), and [url](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/states-of-the-type-attribute.html#url-state)

New Attributes:

- [required](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/common-input-element-attributes.html#the-required-attribute), [autofocus](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/association-of-controls-and-forms.html#autofocusing-a-form-control), [pattern](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/common-input-element-attributes.html#attr-input-pattern), [list](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/common-input-element-attributes.html#the-list-attribute), [autocomplete](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/common-input-element-attributes.html#the-autocomplete-attribute) and [placeholder](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/common-input-element-attributes.html#the-placeholder-attribute)

New Elements

- [`<keygen>`](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/the-button-element.html#the-keygen-element), [`<datalist>`](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/the-button-element.html#the-datalist-element), [`<output>`](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/the-button-element.html#the-output-element), [`<meter>`](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/the-button-element.html#the-meter-element) and [`<progress>`](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/the-button-element.html#the-progress-element)

We could go into forms all day, but here are some resources to explain all this new stuff better.

- [A Form of Madness](http://diveintohtml5.org/forms.html)
- [The Future of The Web: How We’ll Create Form in HTML5](http://www.yourinspirationweb.com/en/the-future-of-the-web-how-well-create-forms-in-html5/)
- [HTML5 Input Types](http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/201004/html5_input_types/)
- [Have a Field Day with HTML5 Forms](http://24ways.org/2009/have-a-field-day-with-html5-forms)
- [Rethinking Forms in HTML5](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/rethinking-forms-in-html5/)
- [HTML5 Forms Are Coming](http://snook.ca/archives/html_and_css/html5-forms-are-coming)

CSS3 brings the wonderful of [Media Queries](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/). Media Queries are so, so, **so** great. Not available in IE8 and below, but will be supported by IE9.

CSS3 has [incrementing counters](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-content/#counters). You can use these to auto-number elements without an ordered-list using the `:before` pseudo-selector and the `content` style when an ordered-list or numbering would be semantically incorrect. (For example, numbering the steps of filling out form fields.)

If you're a fan of CSS Resets, there's an [HTML5 CSS Reset](http://html5doctor.com/html-5-reset-stylesheet/) available from HTML5 Doctor. I have made three additions to this reset for my personal pages:

- `text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;` added to the styles in the definition for `<body>`
- `label` included in definition with `input` and `select` since it needs `vertical-align: middle;`
- styles for `ins` and `:focus` from [Eric Meyer's CSS Reset](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/) added back in

A competing reset called [reset5](http://code.google.com/p/reset5/) is available, but I have not yet evaluated it personally. It is based on *both* the Eric Meyer and HTML5 Doctor resets.

The [HTML5 Security Cheatsheet](http://heideri.ch/jso/) tracks bugs in HTML5 features as implemented in various browsers, and also includes bugs in existing features that are good to keep track of as well.

Using HTML5 elements does not automatically make your code semantic, however. The WHATWG has written an article called [<section> is not just a "semantic <div>"](http://blog.whatwg.org/is-not-just-a-semantic) explaining that it is not simply a container element.

> In HTML 5, there is an algorithm for constructing an outline view of documents. This can be used, for example by AT, to help a user navigate through a document. And <section> and friends are an important part of this algorithm. Each time you nest a <section>, you increase the outline depth by 1 (in case you are wondering what the advantages of this model are compared to the traditional <h1>-<h6> model, consider a web based feedreader that wants to integrate the document structure of the syndicated content with that of the surrounding site. In HTML 4 this means parsing all the content and renumbering all the headings. In HTML5 the headings end up at the right depth for free).
>
>
> ...
>
> If you just blindly convert all the <div>s on your pages to <sections> it's pretty unlikely your page will have the outline you expected. And, apart from being a semantic faux-pas, this will confuse the hell out of people who rely on headings for navigation.

Like everything else in this world, there's a framework for HTML5 web applications called [SproutCore](http://www.sproutcore.com/), built by an [ex-Apple engineer](http://blog.sproutcore.com/post/756343010/the-next-revolution) named Charles Jolley.

In addition to [html5rocks.com](http://html5rocks.com) you can keep up with [html5doctor.com](http://html5doctor.com) and [html5gallery.com](http://html5gallery.com).

Comment: +1 Nice answer!  Think you may be missing a close on one of your code sections somewhere.

Comment: +1 Thanks for the links to the browser compatibility tables! FindMeByIP was especially neat.

Also, In addition to SproutCore, ExtJS just relaunched as Sencha and they seem to be throwing their weight behind HTML 5.

Answer (score 4):

There are the basic layout thing like border-radius, shadows (box/text), rgba support, and so on; This is what CSS3 is most known for. More interesting are the canvas tag, video tag, local storage, websockets and so on that will create much richer user experiences in plain HTML/JS/CSS. These features have the potential to be a great alternative for Flash on the web without the need of additional plugins.

Answer (score 4):

(*This is [my answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/380/) to a similar question over on webapps.stackexchange.com*)

The **Canvas** and **Web Worker Threads** are the most exciting aspects of HTML5 to me. I have written some web apps that make use of those features:

GioAUTHor [sic] makes extensive use of the canvas to let you plot paths on a map and then find the shortest route from the start to the finish (via Dijkstra's algorithm in JavaScript).

[JavaScript Thread Demo](http://www.labouseur.com/projects/jsThreadDemo/index.html) makes limited use of the canvas but shows the use of Worker Threads, complete with demo code. It also makes use of the HTML5 *input type="range"* slider control.

---

HTML5 Browser support is as varied as the browsers themselves. There's a [nice site](http://html5readiness.com/) (in HTML5, natch) about [HTML5 readiness](http://html5readiness.com/) that shows who's ready for what.

Comment: I'd seen that HTML5 Readiness site before, but couldn't remember where - thanks for the link! Really neat, the dual purpose the site serves.

Answer (score 4):

I find the new HTML elements rather interesting...some of them are promising semantic replacements for generic `div`s. The promising new elements include `article`, `section`, `aside`, `figure`, `nav`, `header`, and `footer`, among others. I really like the idea of semantic elements replacing meaningless containers.

Oh yeah, a related item: the much-simplified `doctype` - finally something I can type from memory!

Answer (score 2):

With regards to CSS3 - have alook at http://css3please.com/ to see what you can do.

The later your browser, the more likely you will be able to see the effects.

Answer (score 1):

Audio and video tags allow for presenting media without the need for a plugin like Flash or Silverlight, and most importantly works on the iPhone and iPad browsers.  There are some issues that need to be worked out regarding codecs and digital rights management.

Answer (score 1):

Jeremy Kieth just released a really good book on the topic, "HTML5 for Web Designers". you might want to check that out.

It is the first book from A Book Apart. Highly recommend it to intermediate to advanced designers. A++

http://books.alistapart.com/

**NOTE**: you may have to wait to get a hard copy

Answer (score 1):

This doesn’t offer an opinion on importance, but it’s a useful delta between HTMLs 4 and 5.

- http://www.w3.org/TR/2010/WD-html5-diff-20100624/

My 2¢ on the main improvements:

- `<section>` and the new header outlining algorithm (I did say it was just *my* 2¢)
- new form elements, e.g. `<input type=email>`
- `data-*` attributes
- client-side storage
- native `<audio>` and `<video>`

Answer (score 0):

Because no one has put this yet:

HTML5 is great for what everyone has listed, but it also includes standard geolocation, web workers, web socket, canvas, and localStorage. All these tools are parts of the HTML5 spec, which use a lot of JavaScript behind the scenes to make it happen.