# Can anyone recommend a good HTML 5 book?

Tags: html5, html, books

Specifically about canvas. I have been looking around for a few good one.

Comment: see this question: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/49/what-is-new-in-html5-css3

Answer (score 15):

I really enjoyed reading [Dive into HTML 5](http://diveintohtml5.ep.io/) (an online, free book).

Comment: I think the author plans to publish it when done. I'd buy that!

Comment: +1 beat me to it. Any of the 'Dive into...' books are worth reading.

Answer (score 4):

There's a new HTML5 book from [A Book Apart](http://books.alistapart.com/), written by Jeremy Keith. I have it on order, haven't read it yet, but it has been receiving praise online.

Update: I've since read the book, and it is quite good. It's relatively short, but very focused on giving the essential details, enough for you to get started on.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't yet read all of it since it's very new and still in beta, but [HTML5 & CSS3](http://www.pragprog.com/titles/bhh5/html5-and-css3) from Pragmatic Bookshelf is pretty good so far.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out - I'll add it to my watch list.

Answer (score 1):

This is one of the best book:

[HTML5: Up and Running by Mark Pilgrim](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0596806027)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to learn `<canvas>`, [Mozilla's page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Canvas_tutorial) seems quite good.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to be honest - when it comes to specific languages and technologies, I've pretty much given up on books. The landscape changes way too fast - by the time you have the book, the next release with changes is already on the way. Now, my only books are on things that might change, but if I were to read the book again in 5, 10, or even 15 years, the material is still relevant.

I would instead recommend the [HTML5 Doctor blog](http://html5doctor.com/) and [Dive into HTML5](http://diveintohtml5.org/). There are also a number of other good sites and blogs if you go searching around, and I would stick with them - web resources will be more up-to-date and will cost you less.

Answer (score 0):

Introducing HTML5:

[image: Introducing HTML5]

and [HTML5 For Web Designers](http://books.alistapart.com/)

Answer (score 0):

Am surprised that no one has suggested [HTML5 and CSS3 For the Real-World](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0980846900)

[image]