# Downsides for adapting a site to HTML5/CSS3?

Tags: html5, css3

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Should I use HTML5 and/or CSS3 to build my website?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/18/should-i-use-html5-and-or-css3-to-build-my-website)

I've been wondering if there are any serious downsides for switching a websites code to HTML5/CSS3 now (browser support, browser distribution in the user community) ? 
Would it be a better idea to hold on a little longer ?

Thanks in advance for your replies

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Other than time. Neither is there much of benefit (yet) unless you want to take advantage of some feature you're sorely missing right now.

Technically, the only thing you need to do to convert an (X)HTML document to HTML5 is change the doctype to `<!DOCTYPE html>`